# Read json array without properties with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to do something really simple, but I'm unable getting it right...

Given the following json array:

```
["gate","","vaterlands park","","gabels gate",""]
```

I'm trying to map it using:

```
List<String> names = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://hostname/search?q=" + queryString), List.class);
```

but "names" return empty.

Whats wrong?

Comment: `ObjectMapper mp = new ObjectMapper();List names = mp.readValue("[\"gate\",\"\",\"vaterlands park\",\"\",\"gabels gate\",\"\"]", List.class);` Works fine here. Are you sure your service is returning that exact value?

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't generating an exception? It's quite possible the call to retrieve the URL data failed.

Comment: Theres no exception, but it seems like I'm not able to reach the given URL....

Comment: @jorgen - In that case, try determining why the URL is not returning data first, then once that is working, try your code again.

Comment: Thanks for answears! Got it suddenly to work. And the code are all good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on what you wan't to do.
But I can advice you to use the [JSON's own java classes](http://json.org/java/). They are easy to understand and can be used quite easily.

You can simply use these classes to load the array (if you have the string) it will return a JSONArray which you can use just as you would use any other array.

And you won't need those empty strings, if you only need the actual names that is.